# How to use conditional cors in node js to run in local

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to use conditional cors in node js to run in local.

I am using node js app. Now whenever I need to run in local I have to uncomment lines 11 to 15 and while committing code I am commenting on those lines.

Is there any way I can use some conditions to avoid that bad practice?

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

// to run in local
/* app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000/",
  })
); */

app.get("/api/hello", (_req, res, next) => {
    res.send("hello");
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // some operation 
});


const port =  8000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  logger.info(`Server running on ${port}...`);
});
```

Comment: have a env file with NODE_ENV set to dev? and then check if it is dev?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a conditional statement to enable CORS based on the environment.
To achieve that you can set an environment variable that specifies whether the app is running in *production* or *development* mode.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    })
  );
}
```

`app.use` function for CORS is only executed if the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to `development`.

Install `dotenv` using *npm*:

```
npm install dotenv
```

Create a `.env` file in the root directory of your project, and add the following line:

```
NODE_ENV=development
```

Finally, require `dotenv` at the beginning of your `index.js` file:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this conditional way of distinguishing between local development and production

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

// to run in local
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: "http://localhost:3000/",
    })
  );
}

app.get("/api/hello", (_req, res, next) => {
  res.send("hello");
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // some operation
});

const port = 8000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  logger.info(`Server running on ${port}...`);
});
```